# Heroku still responds to mysubdomain.herokuapp.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have added a custom domain to my Heroku application and it works fine, but the application still responds to {mysubdomain}.herokuapp.com.

To prevent [duplicate content](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359) I would like to stop having my application respond to the subdomain. Is there some setting in Heroku which does this for me, or do I need to code a 301 redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use the rel="canonical" link tag. This tells search engines which URL to use for content that may appear on multiple URLs:

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/correct_url">`

Here's what google has to say: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

(Your use case is explicitly mentioned at the bottom.)

Answer (score 3):

You would need a 301 redirect. Heroku will always respond to the `.herokuapp.com` domain of your app

Answer (score 3):

I created the [**hide_heroku**](https://github.com/ykessler/hide-heroku) gem to handle this- it uses X-Robots-Tag HTTP headers to prevent search engines from indexing anything under ***.herokuapp.com**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to remove the Heroku-provided domain name, either via their web interface or the command-line client.  If you're concerned about it, redirect or add a [`robots.txt`](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) to your site that blocks when accessed via `.herokuapp.com` (I don't know how to do that offhand, sorry).

I suspect Google is reasonably smart about indexing Heroku sites and handles the dual-domain issue itself, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Don't assume that Google is smart about anything search related :)